# xlwings library is not working after deploying with flask API on IIS

Tags: python, flask, iis, xlwings

Given Below code is working fine in `Pycharm` locally, but when we deploy our code on Windows IIS (Client Requirement), its not working.
Its throwing the Error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Your help is highly appreciated.

```py
    filepath = BASE_DIR + '\\data\\abc.xlsm'
    temp_path = BASE_DIR + '\\data\\' + '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, 'xlsm')
    
    shutil.copyfile(filepath, temp_path)
    
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
            
    app1 = xw.App(visible=False)
            
    wt = xw.Book(temp_path)
    
    sht = wt.sheets['Summary']
    sht.range('E5').value = val1
    sht.range('E6').value = val2
            
    
    wt.save(temp_path)
    app1.quit()
```

Comment: Need answer on this. Even I am stuck with the same problem.